# $\| A \|_{L^2} \le \| A \|_{\infty}$ for symmetric matrices $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I found the following statement in a paper ([here](https://doi.org/10.1214/009053607000000109) (see 4th line of page 1940) or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604634.pdf) (towards the middle of page 10)):

> The $L^2$ operator norm of a **symmetric, square** matrix is bounded by its $L^\infty$ operator norm.

The $L^2$ operator norm of a matrix $A$ is defined as:
$$||A||_2 := \sup_{||x|| =1}||Ax||$$ and the $L^\infty$ operator norm of $A$ is defined as: $$||A||_\infty := \max_i \sum_{j}|A_{i,j}|~.$$
So, the paper basically claims that for a symmetric, square matrix $A$, $||A||_2 \le ||A||_\infty$. **Is the statement true at all**? I cannot find the statement anywhere else, and the closest I found, is that for a general $m\times n$ matrix $A$, $||A||_2 \le \sqrt{m}||A||_\infty.$

Comment: @WimC You should probably post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the very last inequality on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)  wikipedia page and note that for a symmetric $A$ the norms $\lVert A \rVert_1$ and $\lVert A \rVert_{\infty}$ are equal.