# $\ell_2$ vs $\ell_{\infty}$ induced norm of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

I'm wondering if the result of this post [$\| A \|_{L^2} \le \| A \|_{\infty}$ for symmetric matrices $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297479/a-l2-le-a-infty-for-symmetric-matrices-a) applies to square matrices that are not symmetric. Of course, for an asymmetrical square matrice $A$ with $\Vert A \Vert_{\infty} \geq \Vert A \Vert_1$, then the same result still applies, but if $\Vert A \Vert_{\infty} \leq \Vert A \Vert_1$ then it is indeterminate.

After testing with a few random matrices of various sizes, it seems to me that the induced $\ell_{\infty}$ norm is indeed an upper bound of the induced Euclidean norm, but I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. E.g.
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}\right\|_2=\sqrt{2}>
1=\left\|\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}\right\|_\infty.
$$

Comment: Amazing, thanks!